# php mail handler shows the code

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm using the following code to create a contact mail form. But whenever I hit the submit button it just shows me the code below in the browser. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
$to = 'email@website.com';
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['comment'];
$headers = 'From: '.$name;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
exit('Your message has been sent.')
?>


<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<title>Welcome</title>
<link href="layout-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div id = "form">
<form action="contact-us.php" method="post">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id = "name" placeholder="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" id = "mail" placeholder="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<textarea type="text" name="comment" id ="mail"placeholder="your comment" rows = 10 cols = 50></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you actually running a web server and accessing your HTML from it as `http://localhost/yourscript.php` rather than `file:///path/to/yourscript.php`? Does the script have a .php extension?

Comment: If you're trying to run this code from the "same" page, then do `action=""` - If that doesn't work, then make sure PHP is installed and running. This is mostly important if running code from a `local` machine. If you are trying to run this from a hosted site, make sure that PHP is available for you to use. To confirm this, create a file called "test.php" with `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` and if nothing shows up or shows up as `code`, then PHP is not running, and/or not parsing PHP properly.

Comment: And once php is running properly, you'll want to wrap that initial php code in a conditional block that only executes when the form is posted. Otherwise it will attempt to run before the user ever sees the form.